# Is there a way to not cut off large tables with page breaks?

Tags: tables, formatting, html, css

Say I have a large table larger than the page, how can I make it so that the second page displays the headers from the previous page and also doesn't split a row in half. Something similar to CSS like:

```
thead { display: table-header-group }
tfoot { display: table-row-group }
tr { page-break-inside: avoid }
```

Comment: try to look at the 'longtable' package and questions here

Comment: A row cannot be split across pages.

Comment: as noted in the answer, `longtable` does this, actually been doing it since before css was invented:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I absolutely love it.

Comment: Now how can you specify the width of a column using longtable?

Comment: @Forwarding it's just standard latex tabular preamble, so for example `p{3cm}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schematic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  % include if you want a different header on the first page
  \toprule
  Header 1 & First page only\\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  % include if you want a header on all or all-but-the-first pages
  \toprule
  Header 2 & All later pages\\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  % include for a footer on all pages
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  some & stuff\\
  and & lots\\
  of & it\\
  ...
  finally & this\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```